# Universal link problem when using http protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

I know that in Apple docs, they say this:

> After you construct the association file, place it in your site’s
> .well-known directory. The file’s URL should match the following
> format:
>
> https:///.well-known/apple-app-site-association You must host the file
> using https:// with a valid certificate and with no redirects.

Our site is not using https, but rather http, but apple-app-site-association file is hosted using https. That is achieved by:

- using letsencrypt and certbot, which gives valid certificate
- some nginx configuration so that all works

I am not a devops, so I don't know details about above, but if we go to ASAA validator (https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) we get this:

[image]

The apple-app-site-association file looks like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "com.xxx.MyApp",
                "paths": [ "/#/new-password/*", "/#/new-password/"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In developer portal, I have enabled associated domains, and in Xcode, Associatied Domains-> Domains setting looks like this:

applinks:mysite.dev.com

Also in ApplicationDelegate I have implemented continueUserActivity method in AppDelegate, but it doesn't trigger, and when I click on a password reset link (from a mailtrap) my application doesn't open, but rather web link is opened (the site).

Link has this structure:

http://mysite.dev.com/#/new-password/a-random-hash-goes-here

Is this problem cause only apple-app-site-association is server on https, but rest of site trough https?

Or, maybe, there is a problem with structure of a file? (specifically paths key)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following, in the `Info.plist` file of your app add the following keys:

1. Add a Key called `NSAppTransportSecurity` as a Dictionary
2. Then add the following subkeys:

- Add a subkey called `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` as Boolean and set its value to YES
- Add a subkey called `NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` as String and set its value to `TLSv1.2`.
  The above would see as the following image:
  [image]

And the code would be like:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.2</string>
    </dict>
```

4. Clean and build the project and test your universal link using the HTTP protocol

If the before steps don't work, you could try to add exceptions for specific domains in your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mysite.dev.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The above is just experimentally, take in mind that if your app doesn't have a good reason to allow HTTP traffic it could be rejected by Apple, I share with you some interesting links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2779#issuecomment-112030880

Regards!

Comment: We decided to go with just serving the apple-app-site-association file through https, and it worked. But, what you suggested maybe could be a solution if https is not an option at all. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

From apples documentation:

> If your app runs in iOS 9 or later and you use HTTPS to serve the apple-app-site-association file, you can create a plain text file that uses the application/json MIME type and you don’t need to sign it

So in yours case I think iOS doesn't tried to download it through HTTPS version and get unsigned `apple-app-site-association`

I see two posible solutions:

1. sign `apple-app-site-association`
2. redirect user anyway at https if you have valid certificate

Comment: Actually it worked just as it is(serving apple-app-site-association file only over https). I just had to delete application from phone, and install it again.